# Cannot find Wifi networks with Ubuntu 18.04.01 MATE

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, network-manager, mate

My problem is that I am unable to discover new wireless networks using the network manager. There is no option to do so under tray, and **System > Preferences > Internet and Network > Network Connections**, yields only previous connections, as shown here:

[image: screen shot of Network Connections window]

Wifi connects automatically to previous wireless network connections (on one now), and can detect new networks from `nmcli`. When restart in presence of new wireless network (e.g. at coffee shop), I get a popup in top right that says "wireless networks are available" but no option to connect.

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network` as per request.

```
      *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: wlp12s0
       version: 61
       serial: 00:21:5c:58:41:33
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl4965 driverversion=4.15.0-42-generic firmware=228.61.2.24 ip=192.168.1.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:25 memory:f6cfe000-f6cfffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:23:ae:06:97:f4
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 firmware=sb v3.04 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:27 memory:f69f0000-f69fffff
```

It really just seems like there is no direct way in Bionic Beaver/MATE to open the list of available wireless networks, because I did not have this problem prior to upgrading from Ubuntu 16 (which is where the network connections I do have came from) and I can connect to Wifi / discover new networks via command line. I'm sure this is something simple that I am missing, however I am new to Linux/Ubuntu and would appreciate any input.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS MATE 1.20.1

thanks

Comment: @CharlesGreen do you know of another forum where I can post the question?

Comment: @CharlesGreen Ubuntu MATE is an official Ubuntu release and it is supported on Ask Ubuntu. Please retract your close vote.

Comment: @Zanna, there is no hardware issue, IMHO. Everything responds properly, both in practice and in diagnostic - there is just no way to discover networks in GUI.

Comment: @Zanna - I have edited the question as per your direction.

Comment: Thanks... +1 thinking about it (sheepishly) I guess this may be nothing to do with your hardware at all but just an issue with the MATE interface. I am also struggling to find the connections interface in MATE 18.04 and with other stuff vanishing from the top bar.

Comment: @Zanna - yes, it seems that way to me. Was able to connect to a wifi hotspot yesterday via command line using nmcli d wifi connect <WiFiSSID> password

Comment: @CobeyWilliamson where is https://ubuntu-mate.community/